# how to get parameter orignal value by receiving it in function

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, position

I am new to jQuery and am trying to write a function for sliding a div on click of another link.

My problem is that the function works when I give direction static but not when I try to give direction dynamic.

Here is my code :

HTML :

```
<div id="popshbtn" onclick="uiSlide(this, '#popwrap', 'right')">
    <p>Feedback</p>
</div>

<div id="popwrap" class="popdnone">
    <h3 class="h3">Support</h3> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#popshbtn{
    background-color: #3385D6;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:16px;
    width:38px; height:188px;
    border:1px solid #2d7dcb;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2%;
    right:0;
    z-index:999999;
}
#popshbtn:hover{
    background:#2d7dcb;
}
#popwrap{
    width:478px; 
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
    padding:10px; 
    background:#f5f5f5;
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    right:-500px;
    margin-left:-500px;
    display:none;
    height:400px;
}
```

jQuery :

```
function uiSlide(ths, target, direction){
console.log(direction);

if( $(target).is(':visible')){

    $(target).hide().animate({
        'direction': '-500px'
    },'fast', function(){
        //call back function
    })

}
else{
    $(target).show().css({
        direction: 0
    },'fast', function(){
        //call back function
    })
}

   }
```

This code doesn't work, unless I give static position instead of direction.

I just want to know, is possible? How do I determine direction of the animation?

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Here is js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/u25Ne/ .

i have upload a image it will help you better to understand
[image]

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle maybe

Comment: here is js fiddle link what i need actually http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/u25Ne/

Comment: I dont get it what you are trying to do. The jsfiddle you have posted seems to work, no? What do you call direction static/dynamic?

Comment: if you can take a look of my js code you can understand what i need in that fiddle am using position: right but i just want to add key dynamic and let me know if you have more question or on that fiddle i have give everything static and in this function am trying to give things dynamic for example this, target div, direction from what side the div animate and blah blah

Comment: There *is* a CSS `direction` property but it takes `rtl` or `ltr`, not a length value, and can't be animated. I expect you want to animate the `left` or `top` property.

Comment: actually i want to know what am trying is possible or not what you are seeing in jsfiddle is i know and that is static everytime we have to give some properties for animate that div but i want only paas it from function and that works that's am trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass object as parameter in animate() jquery API methods, for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/u25Ne/3/

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#popshbtn').click(function () {
    uiSlide(this, '#popwrap', 'right');
  })

  $('#popshbtn').html($('#popshbtn').text().replace(/(.)/g, "$1<br />"));
});

function uiSlide(that, target, direction) {
  var optionObj1 = {},optionObj2 = {};
  optionObj1[direction] = "-500px";
  optionObj2[direction] = 0;

  if ($(target).is(':visible')) {
    $(target).animate(optionObj1, 'fast', function () {
         $(this).hide();
    })

  } else {
    $(target).show().animate(optionObj2, 'fast', function () {

    })
  }

}
```

Comment: This code is working fine can you please describe it what you have done.